Godot "look_at()" function glitching at a specific angle while being used for camera function
I added a lock-on mechanic for the camera in my game. It works great, but for some reason whenever the player is at a certain angle relative to the camera, it has a brief moment where the camera gets flipped around.
A recording of the malfunction occurring, since it's hard to explain it properly in words
Here's the basic code block that makes the camera point at the enemy you're locked on to.
The ImaginaryCam node is just a Node3D I have that's sole purpose is to run the look_at() function so that I can then take the rotation from that to alter my Yaw and Pitch variables, which then run through another system for smooth camera movement.
The Target variable references the object that has been locked on to- in this case, the cube placeholder "enemy" I have in the scene.
    if cam_locked == "target":
        $ImaginaryCam.look_at(target.position, Vector3.UP)
        yaw = $ImaginaryCam.rotation_degrees.y
        pitch = $ImaginaryCam.rotation_degrees.x

I removed all collisions around the player, because I thought maybe the error was caused by the SpringArm3D colliding with one of the basic test objects I had lying around the scene, but that changed nothing.
Edit:
It has been pointed out to me that the problem likely lies in the smooth camera movement code. So here's what that looks like:
yaw_node.rotation_degrees.y = lerp(yaw_node.rotation_degrees.y, yaw, yaw_acceleration * delta)
pitch_node.rotation_degrees.x = lerp(pitch_node.rotation_degrees.x, pitch, pitch_acceleration * delta)


The problem probably isn't in the code you show, it's in your "smooth camera movement" code.  If the previous angle was 355°, and the new computed angle is 5°, is that code going to turn by 10° (wrapping around at zero), or is it going to go the long way around?

Instead of using lerp try to use lerp_angle. Docs: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_@globalscope.html#class-globalscope-method-lerp-angle
